# Copy rows to matrix crashes OpenCV - Visual Studio 2010 C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to copy certain rows from `src` image to new image called gaps. The gaps image will contain only few rows. However the program crashes at the line with `copyTo`. The `Mat src` image is correct, it contains my image because I can view it by `imshow()`.

```cpp
Mat gaps;
int gap = 6;
for (int r = 0; r < src.rows; r++)
{
    if ( r % gap == 0 )
        src.row(r).copyTo(gaps.row(r));
    }
imshow("gaps", gaps);
waitKey(0);
```

I am using OpenCV, Visual Studio 2010 C++ on Windows XP.

I tried to add this:
`gaps.create(CV_8UC3, 2056,2056);` to specify depth and dimensions but it still crashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```cpp
// if you want your background to be black --> Scalar(0,0,0)
Mat gaps = Mat(src.size(), src.type(), Scalar(0,0,0));
```

This is what you'll get, I don't know if that is what you expect/want.

[image]

---

#### Code

```cpp
// set your input image
Mat src = imread("{path to input image}");

// your code with the change I proposed
Mat gaps = Mat(src.size(), src.type(), Scalar(0,0,0));
int gap = 6;
for (int r = 0; r < src.rows; r++) {
    if ( r % gap == 0 )
        src.row(r).copyTo(gaps.row(r));
}
imshow("gaps", gaps);

// create the result image
Mat result = Mat(Size(src.cols * 2, src.rows), src.type(), Scalar(0,0,0));
src.copyTo(result(Rect(0,0,src.cols,src.rows)));
gaps.copyTo(result(Rect(src.cols,0,src.cols,src.rows)));
imshow("result", result);
waitKey();
```

Comment: Thanks that will work. But one more question. How to copy 30 rows from image A  to image B? Something like `A.rows(0,29).copyTo(B.rows(0,29));` does not work. Do I need to use loop too?

Comment: Nope, you can use region of interest. `roi = Rect(...);` and `A(roi).copyTo(roi)`.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar when I have vector of images called main_layers and I want to copy source roi to main_layers? main_layers is `std::vector<cv::Mat> * main_layers;` and when I try `source(roi).copyTo(main_layers);` or something like that I got error.

Comment: @JohnBoe in this case your `main_layers` is a pointer... it won't work that way. I'd recommend you to open a new question. If you want me to take a look, open it and paste the link here.

Comment: I have solved the problem. I found better to use push_back(vector) instead of copyTo(array) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140179/how-to-fill-vector-with-images-in-opencv-c