# How to fill vector with images in OpenCV? C++

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, c++98

I created vector `std::vector<cv::Mat> main_layers;` placed in a class. The vector has not been initiated yet. I have also public member `cv::Mat source;` initiated in constructor initiation list. Now I have a copy method to copy segments of the image to main_layers:

```
void copy(){
    Rect roi;           
    auto primarySegment = main_layers.begin();
    for (int c = 0; c< primaryKernelsLoad; c++)
        {
        if (heightPriority)
            {
            roi = Rect(0, c, size.width, segment1Size);
            source(roi).copyTo(primarySegment);
            auto nx = std::next(primarySegment, 2);
            }
        };
    };
```

Here I have error:
`gaussian.cpp(133): error C2664: 'void cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::OutputArray) const' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'cv::OutputArray'` on line with *copyTo*. How can I get the array from the current image in vector? With regards to C++98, using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: This problem may be easily solved by `source(roi).copyTo(*primarySegment);` The iterator is basically a pointer to an element, so you need to dereference it.

Comment: BTW, `auto` and `std::next`are from C++11, so you shouldn't be using them if you want a C++98 solution.

Comment: @Ken: Well, it compiled with *primarySegment I just wonder that Visual Studio 2010 compiled the C++11 - as I thought VS2010 has C++98 standards. But if it compiled with no problems, then it is OK. Thanks, you can send it as an answer so I can upvote.

Comment: @Ken: yet during runtime I found: debug assertion failed: vector iterator not referencable ... *primarySegment

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly

```
void copy(){
    Rect roi;           
    for (int c = 0; c< primaryKernelsLoad; c++)
        {
        if (heightPriority)
            {
            roi = cv::Rect(0, c, size.width, segment1Size);
            main_layers.push_back(source(roi));
            }
        };
};
```